# Django model imagefield This field is required error

Tags: django, field, required, imagefield

I have a django app which contains the following model:

```
class Business(models.Model, GetDistance):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    .
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    .
    media_dir = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    .
    business_image = models.ImageField(max_length=128, upload_to=upload_business_image_handler, blank=True, height_field='business_image_height', width_field='business_image_width')

    business_image_height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_image_width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then I have also defined a upload handler which is used in the "Business" model:

```
def upload_business_image_handler(instance, filename):
    # determine the upload path
    .
    return file_path
```

I have a form altering the default rendering of the input fields using some widgets, e.g.:

```
business_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50', 'class': 'address'}), required=True)
```

In the form I have not specified the business_image field so that takes the model's defaults. The form in the template has:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
```

and the view code contains:

```
business_form = BusinessForm(request.POST, request.FILES, auto_id='id_registration_%s', branch_list = branch_list, country_list = country_list)
```

Now when I enter some data in the form and select an image for the business_image field everything works as expected. The name of the file is in the Business object and the file is uploaded in the directory determined by the 'upload_business_image_handler'. However when I change the business_image field into:

```
business_image = models.ImageField(max_length=128, upload_to=upload_business_image_handler, height_field='business_image_height', width_field='business_image_width')
```

i.e. remove the 'blank=True' option then I always get a 'This field is required' error, even though I select an image in the business_image form field.

When I insert an 'assert False' in the view I can see the error but I can also see file name and the file object so I don't understand the error message.